# Visualization of data process on BananaPI (in C/ C++)

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, banana-pi

My visualization will show booking status of seats in the bus. You can see whole bus with seats which should change colours and also numbers of free/ busy seats below the main picture. For example: at first there are 42 free green seats so we can see text: "42 free"; "0 busy". Let's say 2 people will sit on two seats. Main pic will change: there will be 40 seats green and 2 red one. Same with the text below: "40 free" and "2 busy".

I managed to synchronize signals from module box (CAN bus line) to BananaPi using TI SN65HVD230D transceiver. I got information from each ID seat section per one frame (seats 1-32 , 33-64 and status of each seat - free, taken, error and not available). I attach receive.c file (http://svn.code.sf.net/p/can4linux/code/trunk/can4linux-examples/receive.c) which I'm using to check the frames (in Terminal typing ./receive -t3 -H).

First I thought about writing a timer which will collect the data from receive.c. each 1s - I wonder how exactly I should declare data to be seen in Qt in my QTimer and QProcess. Could someone provide a example code how it should work?

After I done that I thought to visualize state of seats - I think I should use slots and signals of each seat depending of its state (for free seat - graphic with green seat, and for taken/busy one - a red graphic seat). Is this a good idea?

Thank you in advance for each tip.

Example of frames:

0.167986 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 fc ff ff ff ff ff 3f - noone is sitting

0.167963 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 01 fc ff ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 1 is taken/ busy

0.167972 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 04 fc ff ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 2 is taken/ busy

0.167973 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 10 00 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 3 is taken/busy

0.167973 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 40 00 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 4 is taken/busy

0.167981 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 01 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 5 is taken/busy

0.168021 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 04 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 6 is taken/busy

0.167986 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 10 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 7 is taken/busy

0.167988 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 40 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 8 is taken/busy

0.168017 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 00 fd ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 9 is taken/busy

0.168023 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 00 fc ff ff ff ff 7f - seat no 32 is taken/busy

0.167001 939/0x000003ab : bD ( 8 ): ff ff ff ff ff fc ff ff - seat no 53 is free

0.167023 939/0x000003ab : bD ( 8 ): ff ff ff ff ff fd ff ff - seat no 53 is taken/busy

0.167992 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 00 01 fc ff ff ff ff 7f - seat no 5 & 32 are taken/ busy

0.167986 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 05 00 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 1 & 2 are taken/ busy

0.167965 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 40 01 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 4 & 5 are taken/ busy

0.167971 938/0x000003aa : bD ( 8 ): 50 01 fc ff ff ff ff 3f - seat no 3, 4 and 5 are taken/busy

First of all I'd like to see outputs signals (frames) in Qty. When I push the button after debugging I only see in Application Output:

1. " "
2. Gotowe!
3. 0

and so on after pushing the button each time.

My code:
mywindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
 ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
 ui->setupUi(this);
 }

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QProcess process(this);
QByteArray byteArray = process.readAllStandardOutput();
process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
process.start("test.sh");
process.waitForReadyRead();
qDebug() << process.readAll();
qDebug("Gotowe!");
process.waitForBytesWritten();
process.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << process.exitCode();
```

test.sh is simple bash script to load ./receive with commands "-t3 -H)

```
#!/bin/bash
./receive -t3 -H
```

Comment: I tried to click your attached file receive.c butr says forbidden.

Comment: fixed the link - thank you

Comment: If you have a programming question it would nice to see the code HERE! I have no access to any git repos behind a firewall.